# xCode 4.3.3 - provisioning profiles management

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, osx-lion

After Apple released the iOS 5.1, to debug my software on the devices I was forced to upgrade to xCode 4.3, which for some reason also required my whole OSX to be upgraded to Lion.

What's worse, the new xcode's organizer seems to be broken completely.

1. Unable to refresh the provisioning profile due to the SSL error. Restarting the mac doesn't help. Using Safari, I can access both developer.apple.com and iTunes Connect with no issues.
2. Unable to view the profile's devices (the previous xCode had a panel saying something like "const iPhone 4, const iPhone 3G and 43 other devices"). Is there a way to view the same information in xCode 4.3.3?
3. On the "Provisioning profiles" tab, "Creation" and "Expiration" columns can't be resized, and the dates are truncated with ellipsis.

Are there workarounds?
Can I possibly install xCode 4.2 along with 4.3 on OSX Lion and use it to manage my provisioning profiles? Because the new one is IMO critically broken.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up basically trashing all my old certificates and getting them all again.

They take pains to inform you this won't affect apps you currently have in the store.